# SwiftyJSON: Update Cells in UITableView from JSON response

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm pretty new to iOS Development so please be gentle.

I am using the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) libraries for a project to get and parse a JSON file that is on a server. I also have used this [tutorial](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) to get a UITableView with a few cells "Cell 1" "Cell 2" "Cell 3".

Using the SwiftyJson plugin I have coded:

```
request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
            if(error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error: \(error)")               
                println(req)
                println(res)
            }
            else {
                NSLog("Success: \(url)")
                var json = JSON(json!) 

                var indexValue = 0           
                for (index, item) in enumerate(json) {
                    println(json[index]["Brand"]["Name"])

                    var indvItem = json[index]["Brand"]["Name"].stringValue

                    self.items.insert(indvItem, atIndex: indexValue)

                    indexValue++

                }

            }
    }
```

The println() line works and displays the correct items:

```
println(json[index]["Brand"]["Name"])
```

however I cannot seem to get them to go into the Cells.

At the top of the file, and from the instructions of the tutorial for the  UITableView I have this line:

```
var items = ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3"]
```

There are no errors, the cells just keep their original values. **How do I get the JSON response to update the Cells in the UITableView?**

Edit:

```
 @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var items = ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3"]


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

Comment: normally reloading table do this, can you show the table view data source methods code?

Comment: @rishi added all the code for table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload table after parsing the data, so something like -

```
request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
        if(error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error: \(error)")               
            println(req)
            println(res)
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Success: \(url)")
            var json = JSON(json!) 

            var indexValue = 0           
            for (index, item) in enumerate(json) {
                println(json[index]["Brand"]["Name"])

                var indvItem = json[index]["Brand"]["Name"].stringValue
                self.items.insert(indvItem, atIndex: indexValue)

                indexValue++
            }
                self.tableView.reloadData()  <-----------------------
        }
}
```

Comment: that did work - but it added the items to the beggining of the list. How can I get it to re-write all the data so its just the JSON responses in the tables? Thank you so far - I really appreciate it.

Comment: i am not clear what you are asking now, can you add some screenshot of the issue.
What I get as of now you don't want your pre initialize data, in that case before filling new data, clean the array.

Comment: accepted your answer - sorry for the delay it made me wait until a few mins.